# Is there a category theoretic definition of emergence?

Tags: category-theory

I have come across the idea of emergent properties. It seems this subject saw some increase in activity in the beginning of this century (ie. what articles I have found seems to be from around 2006), and much of it is centered around theoretical physics. Often cited examples are things like temperature, pressure, phase and similar properties that seem to emerge from large assemblies of particles, but are somewhat independent of the nature of the paricles involved. A different example that is somewhat fashionable is the idea that space-time emerges in some way from quantum mechanis (I'm not convinced). The fundamental problem seems to be that there is no consensus about how to model emergence in general, and even some suggestion that it is impossible to apply mathematics to it (which I think is silly). So...

I am interested in the question of whether, say, the topology, the differentialble structure or the dimension of a manifold can be considered an emerging property, and if so, how? And in extension, is there any category theoretical definition of what emergent properties are and how they emerge from more 'atomic' properties?

Comment: You mean ''the whole is greater than the sum of the parts''?

Comment: How is this different from inferring global information from local information?

Comment: @Wuestenfux: Yes, loosely speaking. I'm seeking a more mathematically precise treatment, though.

Comment: @LukasKofler: I'm not sure - could you elaborate? I think 'global information' is perhaps one class of emergent properties, but lacking a concise definition, I can't tell if there may be more.

Comment: Is there a formal definition of what you mean by emergence? Without it would seem really difficult to answer your question (at least to me).

Comment: @GiorgioMossa: well, that is rather what I am looking for, really. But consider gas pressure: a gas consists of a large number of particles, none of which can be said to exert a pressure on anything - pressure is an emerging property. An interesting feature is that the concept is meaningful independently of the nature of the gas - and one might even extend it to abstract dynamic systems. Pressure is what one could call 'statistical' in nature, but I suspect that this is not necessary in general.

Comment: look here https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.11697